# After Running `gem update --system` Bundler packaging gems to vendor/cache/ruby/<version>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When trying to figure out a bundling issue on TravisCI I accidentally ran

```
gem update --system
```

on my Mac. This updated a bunch of things, but I don't know exactly what since I did not save the output. After doing this, in my Rails application, I noticed that when I ran `bundle install --local` it began installing and packaging the gems into `vendor/cache/ruby/<version>` instead of using the ones in `vendor/cache`.

The path in bundler is set to `vendor/cache` but some other setting is causing it to bundle the gems under the ruby version directory. Does anyone know what that setting might be or how I can fix Bundler so it uses the gems in `vendor/cache`?

Gem versions

```
bundler - 2.1.2 (2019-12-20 commit 4da3289eb)
rubygems - 3.1.2
```

Bundler Config

```
$ bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
build.libv8
Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): "--with-system-v8"

cache_all
Set for your local app (/Users/me/forem/.bundle/config): true
Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): true

jobs
Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): 3

path
Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): "vendor/cache"
```

Let me know if any other information would be helpful!

Comment: Is there a '.bundle' directory in your project folder? If yes, edit the path in '.bundle/config' and try installing. Unsure if suited to your situation.

Comment: Was `Gemfile.lock` changed?

Comment: @benjessop there is a .bundle directory, I tried setting the path in there, no luck.
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/cache"

Comment: @Kache Gemfile.lock has not changed at all, I am on our master branch(https://github.com/forem/forem) and simply trying to run the app

Answer (score 1):

Ok folks here is what the issue was.

#### Bundler Explained

[Bundler has **2** settings](https://bundler.io/v2.1/man/bundle-config.1.html)

1. path (BUNDLE_PATH) - The location on disk where all gems in your bundle will be located regardless of $GEM_HOME or $GEM_PATH values. Bundle gems not found in this location will be installed by bundle install. Defaults to Gem.dir. When --deployment is used, defaults to vendor/bundle.
2. cache_path (BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH) - The directory that bundler will place cached gems in when running

#### The Problem

I set BUNDLE_PATH to "vendor/cache". This caused Bundler to try and install all of the gems in "vendor/cache/ruby//" which is not ignored by `.gitignore` and therefore causes a massive dif.

#### Solution:

Reset BUNDLE_PATH back to its default "vendor/bundle"